# SXA Datasource query to refer current item

Tags: sxa

By default, the page Content rendering under the Tabs item is taking datasource as tabs item only. Instead, i need the rendering to take datasource as current page item. I didn't find any datasource query to refer current page item. Kindly let me know if any such query exists or other alternative for this requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a query which is just a `.` character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open **Page Content** rendering parameters and use this query

`query:self::`

The data source will change depending on which page you place your Tabs